# Can't control embedded youtube video

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

Can't control embedded youtube video. As you can see my code doesn't work. Can you help me?

My code: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/tuqowegomo/1/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: It works perfectly in Chrome  40.0.2214.115 m.(**Edit**: and Firefox 35.0.1, and IE11)

Comment: In Firefox doesn't work at all.

Comment: No errors, just nothing.

Comment: What version of Firefox?

Comment: Now it  is 36.0, what's wrong?

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome too

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can add controls=0  to the query string of youtube link

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/trqjVFxMz8Q?autoplay=1&rel=1&enablejsapi=1&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe>
```

here a working [demo](http://output.jsbin.com/ronihaqade)

hope this will help you